# Hessian (as the second covariant derivative) of a smooth function

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

Consider the vector bundle $$\pi\colon \underline{\mathbb R}\to M$$ where $\underline{\mathbb R}$ is the *trivial line bundle* and $M$ is some smooth manifold. Clearly, the sections of $\underline{\mathbb R}$ are the $C^\infty(M)$-functions $f\colon M\to \mathbb R$.

Now let $\nabla^{\underline{\mathbb R}}$ be a connection on $\underline{\mathbb R}$ and let $\nabla^{TM}$ be a connection on the tangent bundle $TM$. We write $\nabla^{\underline{R}}f = df$.

Then we defined the Hessian as the second covariant derivative of $f$ via

$$\nabla^2_{X,Y}f = (\nabla_Xdf)(Y) = XYf - (\nabla Y)f\quad (*)$$

---

### Question 1:

Am I correct in assuming that the above expression $(*)$ is supposed to be

$$\nabla^2_{X,Y}f = (\nabla_Xdf)(Y) = XYf - (\nabla_\color\red{X} Y)f$$ where $X,Y$ are vector fields on $M$?

### Question 2:

If I would like to obtain $(*)$, I suppose it follows from the product rule in the sense that

\begin{align}
\nabla_X(df\otimes Y) &= (\nabla_Xdf)\otimes Y + df\otimes\nabla_XY \\\iff \underbrace{(\nabla_X)(Yf)}_{XYf} &= \underbrace{(\nabla_Xdf)(Y)}_{\nabla^2_{X,Y}f} + (\nabla_XY)f 
\end{align}
and hence

$$\\ \nabla^2_{X,Y}f = XYf - (\nabla_XY)f$$

Since I am always really confused with notations and computations in differential geometry, I'd really appreciate if someone could provide some feedback whether my computations (and assumptions) are correct.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your formula is not quite correct, if you are not assuming that $\nabla_X 1 = 0$. But if you assume that $\nabla_X f = \langle X, df\rangle$, as we usually do, then your formula is correct.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I am assuming that $\nabla_X \operatorname{id} = 0$, thus what I did was fine? And the "red" subscript $X$ is correct, too?

Comment: yes it is correct.

Comment: Thank you vm. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I think $1$ means the constant function, certainly not the identity.

Comment: @TedShifrin, there’s $1$ that’s a section of the bundle and there’s $1$ that’s a scalar. The covariant derivative of the section doesn’t have to be zero. This of course is more obvious for an abstract line bundle.